# Server responds with [ACK] to client's [SYN] which ends up in [RST, ACK] from client

Tags: sockets, tcp, wireshark

Server runs on port `192.168.0.192:51110` and listens for incoming connections. Client `192.168.0.73:5001` tries to connect to the server each 3 secs or so. As you can see at some point the connection was established. After a while the server closed the connection, so did the client. But then something strange started to happen. Client was trying to connect with [SYN], but the server was closed for a while and during that it responeded with [ACK]. At some point it changed - server was listening once again but the result was the same - client was sending 
[SYN], got [ACK] from server and the client responded with [RST, ACK] once again. My question is: Whose fault is it? During the time when client's was struggling with connecting to the server I was able to connect to the server via netcat without a problem.

```
No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
61209   418.027590  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61244   421.081906  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61259   421.538621  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Port numbers reused] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61351   424.652490  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61368   424.653304  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 58  51110 → 5001 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460
61372   424.790294  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61377   425.096394  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=36
61378   425.096592  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=37 Win=65535 Len=0
61383   425.880701  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=37 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=36
61384   425.880880  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=73 Win=65535 Len=0
61389   426.495133  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=73 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=36
61390   426.495307  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=109 Win=65535 Len=0
61395   426.967946  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=109 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=36
61396   426.968117  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=145 Win=65535 Len=0
61418   427.491273  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=145 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=36
61419   427.491456  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=181 Win=65535 Len=0
61422   428.235976  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=181 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=36
61423   428.236161  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=217 Win=65535 Len=0
61428   428.773906  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=217 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=36
61429   428.774082  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=253 Win=65535 Len=0
61431   429.464978  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=253 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=36
61433   429.465225  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=289 Win=65535 Len=0
61434   430.079135  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=36
61435   430.079314  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=325 Win=65535 Len=0
61436   430.569109  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=325 Win=65535 Len=0
61437   430.581167  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=325 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=36
61438   430.581284  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  [TCP Out-Of-Order] 51110 → 5001 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=361 Win=65499 Len=0
61439   430.586241  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [ACK] Seq=361 Ack=2 Win=5839 Len=0
61440   430.591451  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  [TCP Dup ACK 61439#1] 5001 → 51110 [ACK] Seq=361 Ack=2 Win=5839 Len=0
61441   430.598894  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [FIN, ACK] Seq=361 Ack=2 Win=5839 Len=0
61442   430.598963  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=2 Ack=362 Win=65498 Len=0
61443   430.628086  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Port numbers reused] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61444   430.628144  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294955058 Win=65498 Len=0
61445   430.644078  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294955058 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61446   431.115920  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  [TCP ZeroWindow] [TCP Keep-Alive] 51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=0 Ack=4294955058 Win=0 Len=0
61447   431.132461  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294955058 Ack=0 Win=5840 Len=0
61700   433.542616  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61701   433.542677  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  [TCP Window Update] 51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294955058 Win=65498 Len=0
61702   433.550008  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294955058 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61713   436.735938  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61714   436.736047  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  [TCP Dup ACK 61444#1] 51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294955058 Win=65498 Len=0
61715   437.145340  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294955058 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61736   439.544792  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61737   439.544910  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  [TCP Dup ACK 61444#2] 51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294955058 Win=65498 Len=0
61738   439.553303  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294955058 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61747   442.545265  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61748   442.545381  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  [TCP Dup ACK 61444#3] 51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294955058 Win=65498 Len=0
61749   442.556383  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294955058 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61756   445.543206  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61757   445.543319  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  [TCP Dup ACK 61444#4] 51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294955058 Win=65498 Len=0
61758   445.552223  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294955058 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61760   448.716440  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61761   448.716554  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  [TCP Dup ACK 61444#5] 51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294955058 Win=65498 Len=0
61762   448.842308  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294955058 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61763   449.228447  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Port numbers reused] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61765   449.228593  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294946584 Win=65498 Len=0
61769   449.456396  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294946584 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61776   452.085388  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61777   452.085452  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  [TCP Dup ACK 61765#1] 51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294946584 Win=65498 Len=0
61778   452.219830  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294946584 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61788   455.067160  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61792   455.067403  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  [TCP Dup ACK 61765#2] 51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294946584 Win=65498 Len=0
61793   455.074064  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294946584 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61796   458.242349  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61797   458.242462  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  [TCP Dup ACK 61765#3] 51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294946584 Win=65498 Len=0
61798   458.361278  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294946584 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61811   461.107556  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61812   461.107726  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  [TCP Dup ACK 61765#4] 51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=4294946584 Win=65498 Len=0
61815   461.230727  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  5001 → 51110 [RST, ACK] Seq=4294946584 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0
61822   464.175495  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 58  [TCP Retransmission] 5001 → 51110 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
61823   464.175755  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 58  [TCP Previous segment not captured] [TCP Port numbers reused] 51110 → 5001 [SYN, ACK] Seq=1987352337 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460
61824   464.355208  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  [TCP ACKed unseen segment] 5001 → 51110 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1987352338 Win=5840 Len=0
61825   464.502648  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  [TCP Dup ACK 61824#1] 5001 → 51110 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1987352338 Win=5840 Len=0
61826   464.682030  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1987352338 Win=5840 Len=36
61827   464.682033  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 56  [TCP Dup ACK 61824#2] 5001 → 51110 [ACK] Seq=37 Ack=1987352338 Win=5840 Len=0
61828   464.682132  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1987352338 Ack=37 Win=65535 Len=0
61829   465.221480  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=37 Ack=1987352338 Win=5840 Len=36
61830   465.221560  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1987352338 Ack=73 Win=65535 Len=0
61837   465.920001  192.168.0.73    192.168.0.192   TCP 90  5001 → 51110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=73 Ack=1987352338 Win=5840 Len=36
61838   465.920176  192.168.0.192   192.168.0.73    TCP 54  51110 → 5001 [ACK] Seq=1987352338 Ack=109 Win=65535 Len=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks pretty strange for me. The client is using the same source and destination ports directly after a connection was closed. This is not how clients are supposed to work so my guess is that this is some broken client.

The reaction from the server to this strange client is strange too though: it should not just ACK the SYN but either to a SYN+ACK to continue with the handshake or in this case of rapid reuse of the same port better send a RST to the client to abandon the connection attempt. A simply ACK for this does not make really sense.

Comment: Shall the client use a different emphernal port when he disconnected? To run the server I used netcat by simply calling `nc -l -p 51110`

Comment: @MateuszStompór: The client should use a random port which wasn't used recently. It looks like the client binds to a specific source port. Simply remove this explicit binding and the OS kernel will take care of choosing an appropriate source port.

Comment: I'd love to do it but unfortunately I am not the one who provides the client. It happens only on linux/macOS. When I run the server on windows client is able to reconnect to the server with the same source port without any problem

Comment: It turned out that not-changing emphernal port of the client was the problem. Socket was in `TIME_WAIT` state which prevented the client from connecting to the server once again.